# Debug Lists in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, intellij-idea, linked-list

Now I like to use IntelliJ over Eclipse, mainly because the debugging comes to me much easier. When I debug `LinkedList` for example I can see all the items the list contains, which is what I want to debug. Is there any simple way to debug in a similar way in Eclipse?

Right now all I see is the begin and end Object and all the next references. And for lists larger than, lets say 5 items, it's a real pain to click through all those references. I really don't want to print all the items every step.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a Detail Formatter (in the preferences dialog) for the LinkedList type, outputting each of its contained Node's items as you go. Doing that by default would be hazardous depending on the contained object's type. I suspect most cases use an ArrayList, though, which is already easier to debug with.